# Initialize method arguments issue in ruby

Tags: ruby

"In my example, the initialize method expects to receive the two arguments. Once you associate an argument with the initialize method, you can not leave it off. If you do, it will generate an error." - so much for the theory but in my case it is the opposite ;(

```
    class Player
      attr_accessor :name, :age, :score

      def inicialize(name, age, score)
        @name = name
        @age = age
        @score = score
      end

      def to_s
        "Player #{name} is #{age} old and have #{score} points"
      end
    end
```

So I call it simply:

```
player = Player.new("Name", "Surname", 25)
```

but the compiler responds:

```
`initialize': wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 0) (ArgumentError)
```

So, than I do:

```
player = Player.new; player.name = 'Peter'
```

and it works.... why?
When I delete the arguments of inicialize it is the same exact story.

Comment: `initialize` != `inicialize`. Is the `c` version just a typo here, or is that your actual code?

Comment: OMG, what a shame, I think someone should errase this question. Typo BIG time ;( .Thx Marc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should be `initialize`, not `inicialize`.

```
class Player
  attr_accessor :name, :age, :score

  def initialize(name, age, score)
    @name = name
    @age = age
    @score = score
  end

  def to_s
    "Player #{name} is #{age} old and have #{score} points"
  end
end

player = Player.new("Name", "Surname", 25)
#=> #<Player:0x007fca2a4dfbb0 @age="Surname", @name="Name", @score=25>
```